# Paying for testnet coins?

Tags: development, testnet

If testnet coins are [this](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5770/how-do-i-generate-coins-on-testnet-cpu-gpu-fpga-are-there-pools/5778#comment8110_5778) difficult to get, what's the chance people start throwing in some real money to speed along the process?
If only to just have to not wait to test, say if you have an important time sensitive simulation you want to run?

Comment: I don't think people should pay for testnet coins. I was able to finally mine 50 btc. I'll send you enough to get started if you send me your address.

Comment: I don't think they should either, it could happen though, as an unexpected side effect of the whole bitcoin ecosystem.

Comment: This question needs rewording; the primary question seems to be "What are the chances..." which could simply be interpreted as a request for funds (this isn't the best place for that kind of request).

Comment: I think I should make some testnet wallet and faucet to help people with their testnet Bitcoin needs...

Comment: There's always testnet-in-a-box if you really need coins to run something.

Comment: @ThePiachu Last I checked Testnet faucet was down/empty or not working

Comment: @makerofthings7 That's why I should make my own... with blackjack... and hookers! ;)

Comment: Sent a few hundred to tpfaucet, great idea!

Answer (score 6):

I have recently created a TestNet Faucet. It is available on

http://tpfaucet.appspot.com/

I hope this remedies the situation

To answer your question - while there is nothing stopping people from charging for TestNet coins, I think they should be freely available to anyone for testing. It lets newcomers get a feel for what Bitcoin is without risking their money. I hope that a few Bitcoin developers (or even the Bitcoin Foundation) will provide TestNet Bitcoins for free as long as the Bitcoin project is used.

Comment: The server seems to be down!

Answer (score 4):

You can always try to hit up a developer on #bitcoin-dev IRC channel (Freenode).

Also, there is now a faucet:

- http://tpfaucet.appspot.com

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to the great tpfaucet, we also give away free testnet coins at

http://testnet.mojocoin.com

We should help out our fellow developers with testnet bitcoins. There's no need to pay for them.